# verify that element disappear in protractor

Tags: protractor, angularjs-e2e

For wait purposes I use such kind of wait function:

```
    browser.wait(function()
    {
        return browser.isElementPresent(by.repeater('recentName in recentNames').row(0));
    }, 10000);
```

How I can wait for element to disappear from the page? I have project which have lots of modal windows and because elements are always presented on the page I have difficulties and test failures from time to time, because I used wrong elements to wait. For example I have such element which disappear when modal window closes after clicking Enter:

```
<div class="modal-backdrop  in"></div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a custom [waitAbsent()](https://gist.github.com/elgalu/e5be99c10df90d089af6) helper function that actively waits for an element to disappear either by becoming invisible or by not being present.

That helper waits up to `specTimeoutMs` ignoring useless webdriver errors like `StaleElementError`.

Usage: add `require('./waitAbsent.js');` in your [onPrepare](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/a368de0b74db35a90d9a2d8aa48a7e57a45a2aa7/spec/withLoginConf.js#L16) block or file.

Example to wait for the modal to disappear:

```
expect($('.modal-backdrop.in').waitAbsent()).toBeTruthy();
```

Comment: I can confirm that this is the best current solution for this issue. Thanks a lot Leo!

Answer (score 16):

Protractor's [ExpectedConditions](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions) is the recommended way to do this now. You can use it in conjuction with `browser.wait` to create the wait condition for various states, among them `invisibilityOf` (if being hidden) or `stalenessOf` (if being removed from the DOM) an element.

```
browser.wait( EC.invisibilityOf( $('#selector') ), 5000 );
```

Answer (score 1):

If the element is present on the page already, you can get down and dirty with callbacks :D ,  taking advantage of the fact that `browser.wait()` polls the page until the function passed to it evaluates to `true`.

```
browser.wait(function()
    {
        return browser.isElementPresent(by.repeater('recentName in recentNames').row(0)) //if element is already present, this line will evaluate to true
               .then(function(presenceOfElement) {return !presenceOfElement}); // this modifies the previous line so that it evaluates to false until the element is no longer present. 
    }, 10000);
```