# How to wait for element not to be present anymore

Tags: protractor

I have a protractor test that navigates to another url, which cannot be found/resolved in my test environment, so I check if the title is not the previous title.

The test is as follows:

```
it('should navigate to another site in case of click on cancel link', function () {
    page.navigate();
    page.submit();
    protractor.getInstance().ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.wait(function(){
        return element(by.id('submit')).isPresent();
    });
    page.closePage();
    // the title of a 404, dns issue etc is at least different from the previous site:
    expect(browser.getTitle()).not.toEqual('MyDummyTitle')
    protractor.getInstance().ignoreSynchronization = false;
});
```

This works in most browsers, but in Internet Explorer I find that it often is not ready navigating to the non-existing page when the expect is fired.

Can I somehow wait for the 'submit' element to be gone, similar to what I do before firing the closePage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I do in this cases is an [active wait of an element to disappear](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27175396/511069):

Using a custom [waitAbsent()](https://gist.github.com/elgalu/e5be99c10df90d089af6) helper function that actively waits for an element to disappear either by becoming invisible or by not being present.

That helper waits up to `specTimeoutMs` ignoring useless webdriver errors like `StaleElementError`.

Usage: add `require('./waitAbsent.js');` in your [onPrepare](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/a368de0b74db35a90d9a2d8aa48a7e57a45a2aa7/spec/withLoginConf.js#L16) block or file.

Example to wait for `#submit` to be gone:

```
expect(element(by.id('submit')).waitAbsent()).toBeTruthy();
```